# Accessing null object field

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, null

I have a test class in where I give a string value. But for one particular test I need to give null parameter.

```
setversion(versionString)
```

This is parsed in a contract class. In the contract class there is a method to parse string.

```
public void setversion(String versionString){
versionString.trim(); 
//some logic here with string
}
```

When I made a method in the contract class that returns null when null is passed, then I got a review saying that it is not a good practice to change the contract class.

```
 setversion(null);
```

I cannot change anything in the contract class where there is the method setVersion. How can I change the test method.

Comment: why do you need to give it a null argument?

Comment: I need to give it in a test method

Comment: If you cannot change the ``Contract`` class (or ``setversion``), passing ``null`` will result in a NullPointerException and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: why not check if the value is null or not in `setversion(..) method` ?

Comment: Difficult to understand you why you can not change the contract whil still needing for null value... Maybe `setversion("")`

Comment: In the test class I can make changes. But not in contract class

Comment: @learningUser : Why do you need to pass null even in tests when your implementation clearly suggests that an NPE will be thrown? Unless you are expecting an NPE via `@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)`

Comment: This is a complicated test class. so when the null value is passed some critical message is shown.

Comment: Not sure what framework are you using to test but in Mockito you could use `spy` mechanism to mock a single method for a class in your test

Comment: oh yes.. thanks.. I did not think about it

Comment: Have added an answer if you want to close it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use mockito's `spy` mechanism

```
T t = new T();
T tspy = Mockito.spy(t);
Mockito.when(tspy.setversion(null)).thenReturn(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method will return a `NullPointerException`, so without the ability to alter the contract class, you can only test for what you'd expect to happen:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullInput() {
    fail(setversion(null));
}
```

Comment: The test should not fail actually. Because there is some other method dependent upon this which generate messages according to the parameter passed. so if null is passed critical message is shown, something like this